# Mouse disappears on code break

Tags: c++, ogre3d

I am using Ogre3D and sometimes when there is a break (or an exception) and it breaks into visual studio, my mouse cursor fails to appear. This is very annoying as most of the time I have to restart the game because I cannot watch any variables when it breaks. Everything else works, just the mouse disappears and stays that way until I press Shift+F5 to end debugging OR I remove the break and hit continue, then exit out of the game normally (in the case of exceptions, I have no choice but to end debugging).

I think this problem is not due to Ogre3D itself. In any case, I hope somebody has a solution to this very annoying problem.

Comment: have you tried alt tabbing into another application to regain the mouse?

Comment: yes I have, the mouse stays invisible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the solution (not by myself, but with help :)

A direct link to the discussion of the issue: [Ogre3D Forum](http://www.ogre3d.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=59905)

In case that link ever goes down, here is the quick answer which I hope will help somebody in the future with the same problem.

> OIS locks the mouse exclusively for
>   the app and if you want it to appear,
>   set the mouse to non-exclusive mode. - syedhs

To set it to non-exclusive (partial code, if you ran into this problem then you know where this goes)

```
  paramList.insert(std::make_pair(std::string("w32_mouse"), 
    std::string("DISCL_FOREGROUND" )));
  paramList.insert(std::make_pair(std::string("w32_mouse"), 
    std::string("DISCL_NONEXCLUSIVE")));
```

You can change `DISCL_FOREGROUND` to `DISCL_BACKGROUND` depending on whether your application requires background access or not [MORE INFO](http://www.falloutsoftware.com/tutorials/di/di2.htm)